# How to import data from Excel to C# into an array and perform arithmetic operations with them?

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel file like the one in the picture. Can you please help write code with which you can write this data to an array and use it further for arithmetic operations? I need this on assignment at the university, and I don't fumble in programming at all (μ_μ)
[image]

I tried to write smth from the video tutorial, so if it helps you understand the problem, here is the code below

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private double[,] excelTable;

        private int totalRows = 0;

        private int totalColumns = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DialogResult res = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

                if (res == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ExcelPackage excelFile = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName));

                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

                    totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    totalColumns = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

                    excelTable = new double[totalRows, totalColumns];

                    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= totalRows; rowIndex++)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<string> row = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString());
                        List<string> list = row.ToList<string>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                        {
                            excelTable[rowIndex - 1, i] = Convert.ToDouble(list[i].Replace('.', ','));
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++)
                        {
                            richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(excelTable[i, j]);
                        }
                        richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("No file selected");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to save your Excel file as a CSV (comma-separated values) file? This will make it much easier to read the data using C# and you will still be able to open and edit it in Excel.

Comment: Also, unless you particularly need a fancy user interface, I would suggest you use a C# console application and avoid the need for any graphical controls. Read the data straight into an array (or other collection). This could be as simple as: ExcelFile ef = new ExcelFile(); ef.LoadCsv("DataFile.csv"); (depending on your preferred approach, the nature of your CSV file, your target .NET version, etc). There are many articles online explaining how to do this.